# Can I use row-level-security for application users?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

For my webservice I use a *PostgreSQL* database which supports row-level-security to prevent users accessing rows of a table they are not supposed to read/access. I would like to use this functionality to prevent a user accessing data from another user (either due to a bug, altered webservice request, SQL injection, etc).

I understand the purpose is actually meant for a database user, but I am wondering if it is wise or common to create a shadow-user in the database for every "application" user as well. (the database is of course not directly accessed and rather through a WSGI, therefore the shadow user)

FYI: This is technically a XY-problem. For example, my actual intention is to prevent that a user requested his profile and accidentally or corner-case data from another profile gets send back. Row-Level access looked promising

Answer (score 1):

[Row security policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) are general SQL expressions, so you are not required to use database users. However, the policy has to know what the current user is, and this is easier with `current_user` than with some other setting. (It would be possible to use `current_setting('my_app.app_user')`, but that requires you to SET this value in every connection, and is not protected against changes made by injected SQL code.)